# Docker container not inheriting dns settings from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

For some reason a Docker Container I have created as part of a stack using a Docker Compose file in Docker Swarm does not have the correct networking settings.

Reading the Docker documentation about networking [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname) I see that:

`By default, a container inherits the DNS settings of the Docker daemon, including the /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf.You can override these settings on a per-container basis.`

However when I create a new stack using a Docker Compose file the /etc/resolv.conf file inside the container is nothing alike to the /etc/resolv.conf file of the host. As a result I cannot connect to a database server on the same network.

Right now /etc/resolv.conf on the host looks like this:

`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.254
search localdomain`

And inside the Docker container it looks like this:

`search localdomain
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0`

To create the services I use the following command:

`docker stack deploy --compose-file config.compose --with-registry-auth`

The Docker Compose file is rather large but is basically just a large list of services it should start. There are no networking options defined in the Docker Compose file.

As a test I also started a service not as a stack and this service did inherit the /etc/resolv.conf file correctly.

Anyone know why the dns settings are not correctly inherited from the host?

System specs:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Docker: 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct dns setting set on the docker daemon https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/